# Ability to modify profile on iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The iOS-app should provide (at least) the same features as the site and the ability to edit your profile is not so unimportant.

In my opinion, the user should be able to change the every single info-field in his profile (including, but not limited to nickname, description, profile picture) by pressing an "Edit" button which should be located somewhere on his or her profile view.

[image: Current profile view]

Comment: You are running on reserve battery power…

Comment: I too would really like this functionality! Hopefully app devs find this.